# Keeping the UI visually updated while running an expensive operation on the UI thread

Tags: wpf, user-interface, asynchronous, dispatcher, begininvoke

In my WPF app, I need to run an expensive operation on my UI thread (let's call it `ExpensiveUIOperation()`), and I want to keep the UI up to date to track it's progress.

To track progress, I simply have a `TextBlock`, whose `Text` property is bound to an integer dependency property `PercentageComplete`. During `ExpensiveUIOperation()`, I simply set the value of `PercentageComplete` as required.

Now, I understand enough about threading to know that if I simply ran `ExpensiveUIOperation()` on my UI thread, that the TextBlock would not *appear* to keep up to date, as the UI thread would be blocked, stopping any interface updates.

And so I thought I could do it asynchronously like this:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(ExpensiveUIOperation), DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

But that is still not working. The text block is not visually updated until the operation completes.

**Is there a way to do this?**

Unfortunately in this situation I cannot use a background thread, as the operation makes heavy use of objects owned by the UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're stuck, UI operations have to occur on the UI thread, and while that occurs no UI updates will happen.  You could do the equivalent of an `Application.DoEvents` in WPF by creating a new dispatcher frame (http://dedjo.blogspot.com/2007/08/how-to-doevents-in-wpf.html) but it is dangerous, you will catch the UI in the middle of updates and not a good thing to do.

Is the expensive UI operation really a CPU-intensive, UI-only operation?  Nothing that can be done with a View Model object graph and then finally bound to the UI, for example?

Comment: Thanks for that, I eventually used a ApplicationDoEvents approach. To minimise the danger, I run the whole operation on a second UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

> Unfortunately in this situation I cannot use a background thread, as the operation makes heavy use of objects owned by the UI thread.

That is not a good enough reason to abuse the UI-thread like this. Use the Dispatcher when accessing those elements (see the [treading model reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx)), or properly bind your view to relevant properties and you will not even need to do that as updates are queued to the UI internally.

Comment: Thanks for that. My 'expensive operation' builds a FixedDocument object (creates it, adds FixedPage objects, etc.) I've since learned that because FixedDocument is a DispatcherObject, I have to create it in the same thread as the DocumentViewer that is eventually used to display it. Hence my need to do it on the UI thread. I did find another solution in which a guy in a similar situation created a FixedDocument in the background thread, serialised it to disk, then loaded it in the UI thread. But I've found my own workaround now.